# Resignation letter to a new manager

Tags: management, resignation, quitting, manager

So I've worked at the same restaurant for 8 years and I'm graduating college in 3 months. About a year ago there was a change in management. My long time manager was forced out by the district manager due to personal conflict. The replacement manager was completely incompetent and allowed the store to fall into near disrepair. Turn over sky rocketed, the restaurant started getting dirty,food quality plummeted, and customers started to complain. I recently stepped down as a shift supervisor due to the stress of working with totally untrained new employees and the extra burden of picking up after a manager completely lost at sea. I had been planning to quit very soon when the new manager was fired. Now another manager has been brought in but I am still planning on quitting next week. I have actually yet to meet her so I am wondering how I write a resignation letter to someone who I've never met, that didn't hire me, and that hasn't been with the company for longer than 2 weeks. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 32):

The same way you write a resignation letter to one you do know. "I regret to inform you that I will be resigning my position with [company], effective on [date]. Please consider this note my official [number] weeks' advance notice. Let me know if there are special duties, such as helping to train my replacement, that you want me to spend the remaining time on."

This is official business communication. Short is good Clear is good. Polite is good. Short, clear, complete and polite wins bigtime. The fact that she's new on the job is irrelevant; though if you get a chance outside the official statement it might be courteous to say "don't worry, it isn't about you, it was just time for me to move on."

Comment: IMO it's easier to give a resignation letter to one you don't know. +1 for the short and to the point.

Comment: I would just modify one single word in the suggestion, if it fits for the situation of the asker. If @tone90 considers it to be a valid option to stay if the new manager shows necessary values, I would rather phrase as "to inform that I [intend/plan] to resign". This has the slight message that he is open for discussion, however seeing poor chances to be convinced to stay.

Answer (score 4):

What you write on a letter and what you say in person can be different. The former is official, and the latter can make you a human being.

What I mean by that is that you can:

a) Provide a formal letter of resignation. It doesn't ave to be specific to the new manager. You can address it "To whom it may concern".

b) Speak to the new manager if you get the chance. If they seem receptive/nice then you can explain your reasons in gritty detail. Provide some pointers about what they can do to turn the place around, and wish them luck. However, you can state the time has come to part company. Its your life, you don't have to work there. If they are a decent person and manager they will respect that wish and your approach. They might even thank you for taking the time to try to help.

If they are NOT recptive, just get out of there. "Here is my letter. Good luck and goodbye.". Life is too short!

The above will show that you have professional integrity, and that you are a good person.

Comment: This is true, poetic, and useful. It would have made a good comment. - The downvotes are undoubtedly because it does not address nor answer the question.

Comment: I've expanded my answer.